# There is no support getInstant in iText

Tags: java, netbeans, itext

`getInstance()` does not work anymore in *iText*. What can I do for it?

```java
private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    try{
        Document document = new Document();
        PdfWriter.getInstance(document, new FileOutputStream("New report.pdf"));
        document.open();
        document.add(new Paragraph("New "));              
        document.close();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
    }
}
```

There is a compiling error:

> *com/mycompany/aqaclutrure/Finalview.java cannot find symbol*

Comment: Do you get a compilation error? If so please include it in the question

Comment: There is a compiling error                                                                       com/mycompany/aqaclutrure/Finalview.java cannot find symbol

Comment: What type does your Document have? You will need a `com.itextpdf.text.Document`. Btw, it's helpful to add the imports when you post a question or answer!

Comment: What is the idea of  "Type of document"?

Comment: `com.sun.xml.txw2.Document`, `javax.swing.text.Document`, `org.dom4j.Document`, `org.w3c.dom.Document`, ... I could guess more if you like. What type means what type.

Comment: *"getInstance does not work any more"* - what did you change since it last worked? Did you by chance update from iText 5.x to iText 7.x (which has a completely new architecture)?